# PHP stdclass json decode

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a few values from a `json_decode` output. I have a script that connects to Tumblr API after granting access. I have gotten to this point after decoding the `object` `stdClass`. The problem I'm having now is trying to echo out only the "name" of the blog and "follower" count. The example below has two blogs instead of one. So the blogs name are "blogone" and "blogtwo" in the example below.

```
 {"meta":{"status":200,"msg":"OK"},"response":{"user":{"name":"blogone","likes":0,"following":0,"default_post_format":"html","blogs":[{"name":"blogone","url":"http:\/\/blogone.tumblr.com\/","followers":234,"primary":true,"title":"Untitled","description":"","admin":true,"updated":1354139573,"posts":0,"messages":0,"queue":0,"drafts":0,"share_likes":true,"ask":false,"tweet":"N","facebook":"N","facebook_opengraph_enabled":"N","type":"public"},{"name":"blogtwo","url":"http:\/\/blogtwo.tumblr.com\/","followers":0,"primary":false,"title":"dfgdfg","description":"","admin":true,"updated":0,"posts":0,"messages":0,"queue":0,"drafts":0,"share_likes":false,"ask":false,"tweet":"N","facebook":"N","facebook_opengraph_enabled":"N","type":"public"}]}}}
```

The questions is how do I echo out the blog "name" and "follower" count per each blog. Sometimes there is only one blog and sometimes there can be multiple blogs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$jsonString = '{"meta":{"status":200,"msg":"OK"},"response":{"user":{"name":"blogone","likes":0,"following":0,"default_post_format":"html","blogs":[{"name":"blogone","url":"http:\/\/blogone.tumblr.com\/","followers":234,"primary":true,"title":"Untitled","description":"","admin":true,"updated":1354139573,"posts":0,"messages":0,"queue":0,"drafts":0,"share_likes":true,"ask":false,"tweet":"N","facebook":"N","facebook_opengraph_enabled":"N","type":"public"},{"name":"blogtwo","url":"http:\/\/blogtwo.tumblr.com\/","followers":0,"primary":false,"title":"dfgdfg","description":"","admin":true,"updated":0,"posts":0,"messages":0,"queue":0,"drafts":0,"share_likes":false,"ask":false,"tweet":"N","facebook":"N","facebook_opengraph_enabled":"N","type":"public"}]}}}';
$jsonObject = json_decode($jsonString);
$result = '';
foreach ($jsonObject->response->user->blogs as $blog) {
    $result .= $blog->name . ' - ' . $blog->followers . '<br/>' . "\n";
}
echo $result;
```

Comment: Wow this is a first for me. First answer that worked correctly first time! Thank you and now I understand how it works. :D